# R values that go into matrix multiplication

Tags: r, data.table, matrix-multiplication

What is the fastest approach to saving unique values that go into matrix multiplication (without 0)?
For example, if I have a data.table object

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(j3=c(3,0,3),j5=c(0,5,5),j7=c(0,7,0),j8=c(8,0,8))
```

I would like to see which unique values go into A*transpose(A) (or `as.matrix(A) %*% as.matrix(t(A))`). Right now, I can do it using for loops as:

```
B=t(A)
L = list()
models = c('A1','A2','A3')

for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(B)){
        u = union(unlist(A[i,]),B[,j])
        u = u[u!=0] # remove 0
        L[[paste(models[i],models[j])]]= u
    }
}
```

**However, is there a faster and more RAM-efficient way?** The output doesn't have to be a list object, as in my case, it can be a data.table (data.frame) as well. Also, the order of values is not important. For example, `3 5 8` is as good as `5 3 8`, `8 5 3` etc.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: So `as.matrix(A) %*% as.matrix(t(A))` is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  
[1,]   73    0   73  
[2,]    0   74   25
[3,]   73   25   98
```

The first element is calculated as `3*3+0*0+0*0+8*8 = 73`, the second element is `3*0+0*5+0*7+8*0 = 0`, etc. I need unique numbers that go to this calculation but without 0.

Therefore outputs (saved in the list L) are:

```
> L  
$`A1 A1`  
[1] 3 8

$`A1 A2`  
[1] 3 8 5 7

$`A1 A3`   
[1] 3 8 5

$`A2 A1`  
[1] 5 7 3 8

$`A2 A2`  
[1] 5 7

$`A2 A3`   
[1] 5 7 3 8

$`A3 A1`  
[1] 3 5 8

$`A3 A2`   
[1] 3 5 8 7

$`A3 A3`   
[1] 3 5 8
```

Once again, the output doesn't have to be a list object. I would prefer data.table if it is doable. Is it possible to rewrite my approach as Rcpp function?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to get?  Maybe add (some of) the final `L` list to your question, and explain what it contains. It looks like the `Ai Aj` entry contains `setdiff(unique(c(A[i,], A[j,])), 0)` (after converting A to a matrix), but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for adding `L`, but what I was really suggesting is that you explain why (for example) `L[["A1 A1"]]` should be `c(3, 8)`.  How is that related to `A`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added the explanation above the L list. So, `L[["A1 A1"]]` gives unique numbers that go into the calculation of the first element of `as.matrix(A) %*% as.matrix(t(A))`; which is `3*3+0*0+0*0+8*8 = 73`. Here we have only 3 and 8, and these values are saved.

Comment: Might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: It is difficult to explain (it comes from larger problem involving data.tables of order 300x40000000), but I realize it can solve question of having values other than 0 in column and giving all combinations quickly. Then it goes into optimization. So, this is a middle step and it is essential to be quick.

Comment: It may be a good idea to explain what your problem with those large datatables is And why they are so large, etc. the whole picture.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to transpose the data.table : with transposition you compare rows to cols, but without you could simply compare rows to rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Potential optimizations

Following up on @user2554330's answer, note that if `A` is an `m`-by-`n` matrix, then `AAT = A %*% t(A)` (equivalently `tcrossprod(A)`) is an `m`-by-`m` symmetric matrix. `AAT[i, j]` and `AAT[j, i]` are computed using the same entries of `A`, so you only need to inspect `m*(m+1)/2` pairs of rows of `A`, not `m*m`.

You can do even better by finding and caching the unique elements of each row *before* pairing them. Preprocessing in this way avoids redundant computation and should noticeably improve performance when `m << n`.

##### Limitations

Another aspect of the problem is how `unique` works under the hood. `unique` has an argument `nmax` that you can use to specify an expected maximum number of unique elements. From `?duplicated`:

> Except for factors, logical and raw vectors the default `nmax = NA` is equivalent to `nmax = length(x)`. Since a hash table of size `8*nmax` bytes is allocated, setting `nmax` suitably can save large amounts of memory. For factors it is automatically set to the smaller of `length(x)` and the number of levels plus one (for `NA`). If `nmax` is set too small there is liable to be an error: `nmax = 1` is silently ignored.

> Long vectors are supported for the default method of `duplicated`, but may only be usable if `nmax` is supplied.

These comments apply to `unique` as well. Since you have a 300-by-`4e+07` matrix, you would be evaluating (with preprocessing):

- `unique(<4e+07-length vector>)`, 300 times,
- `unique(<up to 8e+07-length vector>)`, `299*300/2` times.

That can consume a lot of memory if you don't know anything about your matrix that might allow you to set `nmax`. And it can take a long time if you don't have access to many CPUs.

So I agree with comments asking you to consider *why* you need to do this at all and whether your underlying problem has a nicer solution.

##### Two answers

FWIW, here are two approaches to your general problem that actually take advantage of symmetry. `f` and `g` are without and with preprocessing. `[[.utri` allows you to extract elements from the return value, an `m*(m+1)/2`-length list, as if it were an `m`-by-`m` matrix. `as.matrix.utri` constructs the full, symmetric `m`-by-`m` list matrix.

```r
f <- function(A, nmax = NA) {
  a <- seq_len(nrow(A))
  J <- cbind(sequence(a), rep.int(a, a))
  FUN <- function(i) {
    if (i[1L] == i[2L]) {
      x <- A[i[1L], ]
    } else {
      x <- c(A[i[1L], ], A[i[2L], ])
    }
    unique.default(x[x != 0], nmax = nmax)
  }
  res <- apply(J, 1L, FUN, simplify = FALSE)
  class(res) <- "utri"
  res
}

g <- function(A, nmax = NA) {
  l <- lapply(asplit(A, 1L), function(x) unique.default(x[x != 0], nmax = nmax))
  a <- seq_along(l)
  J <- cbind(sequence(a), rep.int(a, a))
  FUN <- function(i) {
    if (i[1L] == i[2L]) {
      l[[i[1L]]]
    } else {
      unique.default(c(l[[i[1L]]], l[[i[2L]]]))
    }
  }
  res <- apply(J, 1L, FUN, simplify = FALSE)
  class(res) <- "utri"
  res
}

`[[.utri` <- function(x, i, j) {
  stopifnot(length(i) == 1L, length(j) == 1L)
  class(x) <- NULL
  if (i <= j) {
    x[[i + (j * (j - 1L)) %/% 2L]]
  } else {
    x[[j + (i * (i - 1L)) %/% 2L]]
  }
}

as.matrix.utri <- function(x) {
  p <- length(x)
  n <- as.integer(round(0.5 * (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * p))))
  i <- rep.int(seq_len(n), n)
  j <- rep.int(seq_len(n), rep.int(n, n))
  r <- i > j
  ir <- i[r]
  i[r] <- j[r]
  j[r] <- ir
  res <- x[i + (j * (j - 1L)) %/% 2L]
  dim(res) <- c(n, n)
  res
}
```

Here is a simple test on a 4-by-4 integer matrix:

```r
mkA <- function(m, n) {
  A <- sample(0:(n - 1L), size = as.double(m) * n, replace = TRUE, 
              prob = rep.int(c(n - 1, 1), c(1L, n - 1L)))
  dim(A) <- c(m, n)
  A
}

set.seed(1L)
A <- mkA(4L, 4L)
A
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    0    2    3
## [2,]    0    1    0    0
## [3,]    2    1    0    3
## [4,]    1    2    0    0

identical(f(A), gA <- g(A))
## [1] TRUE

gA[[1L, 1L]] # used for 'tcrossprod(A)[1L, 1L]'
## [1] 2 3

gA[[1L, 2L]] # used for 'tcrossprod(A)[1L, 2L]'
## [1] 2 3 1

gA[[2L, 1L]] # used for 'tcrossprod(A)[2L, 1L]'
## [1] 2 3 1

gA # under the hood, an 'm*(m+1)/2'-length list
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] 2 1 3
## 
## [[7]]
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## [[8]]
## [1] 1 2
## 
## [[9]]
## [1] 2 1 3
## 
## [[10]]
## [1] 1 2
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "utri"

mgA <- as.matrix(gA) # the full, symmetric, 'm'-by-'m' list matrix
mgA
##      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
## [1,] integer,2 integer,3 integer,3 integer,3
## [2,] integer,3 1         integer,3 integer,2
## [3,] integer,3 integer,3 integer,3 integer,3
## [4,] integer,3 integer,2 integer,3 integer,2

mgA[1L, ] # used for first row of 'tcrossprod(A)'
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 2 3 1

## If you need names
dimnames(mgA) <- rep.int(list(sprintf("A%d", seq_len(nrow(mgA)))), 2L)
mgA["A1", ]
## $A1
## [1] 2 3
## 
## $A2
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## $A3
## [1] 2 3 1
## 
## $A4
## [1] 2 3 1

## If you need an 'm'-by-'m' 'data.table' result
DT <- data.table::as.data.table(mgA)
DT
##       A1    A2    A3    A4
## 1:   2,3 2,3,1 2,3,1 2,3,1
## 2: 2,3,1     1 1,2,3   1,2
## 3: 2,3,1 1,2,3 2,1,3 2,1,3
## 4: 2,3,1   1,2 2,1,3   1,2
```

And here are two benchmarks on two large integer matrices, showing that preprocessing can help quite a bit:

```r
set.seed(1L)
A <- mkA(100L, 1e+04L)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(A), g(A), times = 10L, setup = gc(FALSE))
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##  f(A) 2352.0572 2383.3100 2435.7954 2403.8968 2431.6214 2619.553    10
##  g(A)  843.0206  852.5757  858.7262  858.2746  863.8239  881.450    10

A <- mkA(100L, 1e+06L)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(A), g(A), times = 10L, setup = gc(FALSE))
## Unit: seconds
##  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  f(A) 290.93327 295.54319 302.57001 301.17810 307.50226 318.14203    10
##  g(A)  72.85608  73.83614  76.67941  76.57313  77.78056  83.73388    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can try this

```
f <- function(A, models) {
AA <- replace(A, A == 0, NA)
setNames(
  c(t(outer(
    1:nrow(A),
    1:nrow(A),
    Vectorize(function(x, y) unique(na.omit(c(t(AA[c(x, y)])))))
  ))),
  t(outer(models, models, paste))
)
}
```

which gives

```
$`A1 A1`
[1] 3 8

$`A1 A2`
[1] 3 8 5 7

$`A1 A3`
[1] 3 8 5

$`A2 A1`
[1] 5 7 3 8

$`A2 A2`
[1] 5 7

$`A2 A3`
[1] 5 7 3 8

$`A3 A1`
[1] 3 5 8

$`A3 A2`
[1] 3 5 8 7

$`A3 A3`
[1] 3 5 8
```

---

If you care about the speed, you can try

```
lst <- asplit(replace(A, A == 0, NA), 1)
mat <- matrix(list(), nrow = nrow(A), ncol = nrow(A))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- combn(lst, 2, function(...) unique(na.omit(unlist(...))), simplify = FALSE)
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)]
diag(mat) <- Map(function(x) unname(x)[!is.na(x)], lst)
L <- c(t(mat))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the additional information in your edits.  From what you posted, it appears that for all pairs of rows of a matrix or data table `A`, you want the unique non-zero values in those two rows.

To do that efficiently I'd suggest ensuring that `A` is a matrix.  Row indexing in dataframes or data tables is a lot slower than doing so in matrices.  (Column indexing can be faster, but I doubt if it's worth transposing the table to get that.)

Once you have a matrix, `A[i, ]` is a vector containing the values in row `i`, and that's a pretty fast calculation.  You want the unique non-zero values in `c(A[i, ], A[j, ])`.  The `unique` function will produce this, but won't leave out the zeros.  I'd suggest experimenting.  Depending on the contents of each row, it is conceivable that leaving the zeros out of the rows first before computing the unique entries could be either faster or slower than calculating all the unique values and deleting 0 afterwards.

You say you want to do this for a few hundred rows, but each row is very long.  I'd guess you won't be able to improve much on nested loops:  the time will be spent on each entry, not on the loops.  However, you could experiment with vectorization using the `apply()` function, e.g.

```
result <- vector("list", nrows)
for (i in 1:nrows) 
  result[[i]] <- apply(A, 1, function(row) setdiff(unique(c(row, A[i,])), 0))
```

This will give a list of lists; if you want to examine entry i, j, you can use `result[[c(i,j)]]`.